# How to render a log file in browser through url using node js?

Tags: node.js, express, render

I am trying to render a log file in the browser by hitting a url. The log file is placed in my local (logs/app.log). I am stuck with this for a day.. Please find my node js code.

```
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
app.use('/logs', express.static(__dirname + '/logs'));

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Maybe you can use `Server Sent Events(SEE)` with a file listener and stream the log file back to the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an API as below:

```
app.get('/logs', function (req, res, next) {

    var filePath = "path to your log file";

    res.sendFile(filePath, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        next(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Sent the logs..');
    }
  });
});
```